# Create unique integer from two integers

Tags: java, database, postgresql

A little background to understand what I am trying to archive.
I have a max. of 1000 databases, each with an unique ID. The structure of these databases is identical, but the data is different (one database per customer).
So let's say, each of the databases has one table named table1:

DB1:

```
+----+---------+------+
| ID |  col1   | col2 |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | String1 |   23 |
|  2 | String2 |   56 |
|  3 | String3 |   35 |
+----+---------+------+
```

DB2:

```
+----+---------+------+
| ID |  col1   | col2 |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | String4 |   34 |
|  2 | String5 |   54 |
|  3 | String6 |   23 |
+----+---------+------+
```

We are rewriting the application, using only one DB for all customers. In the beginning, we have to use both system parallel, and I need some way to create a table in the new Database, with unique IDs. And I want to be able to calculate back from the new ID to the DB ID and the old ID. So the new table will be:

```
+----+---------+------+
| ID |  col1   | col2 |
+----+---------+------+
|  ? | String1 |   23 |
|  ? | String2 |   56 |
|  ? | String3 |   35 |
|  ? | String4 |   34 |
|  ? | String5 |   54 |
|  ? | String6 |   23 |
+----+---------+------+
```

What can I add as a ID (only restriction: unique!) so I have a distinct match between the new and old data.

Of course I could just add a column sourceDB and sourceID to each table of the new DB, but I would prefer not to.

Some specs: I have around 1000 DBs with around 200 tables each. Even the biggest table does not habe more than 1 million rows.
The new DB is postgres, and we prpgram in Java

Comment: Why do you not prefer the compound primary key solution? It seems the clearest solution to me and it has the advantage to query your tables for a single "customer" (it could be a `customer_id` instead of a `source_db` if you plan a customer table too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a classical questions of dividing up an identifier space. Assuming that you have a n-bit resp m-bit `int` type representing the id in your tables, then by using a max(n, m) + 1 bit identifier you can distinguish all values by the leading bit. If you need to distinguish more than two tables, you need to increase the size of the prefix to a suitably large number of bits.

Of course you can also choose to further subdivide the spaces, if you are sure that you have some leading bits left somewhere to do that, much like CIDR in IP-networks allows you to further and further subdivide address spaces.

Implicitly that does the same as creating the sourceDB column, except that the resulting IDs are always unique, without looking up the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one database per client then I would create a master table (with all the client fields, including the old db details if needed) and reference client id in the new table, e.g.:

`Client (ID, Name, source db ..)`

New table:

`Table (ID, col1, col2, client_id)`

`ID` can be primary key in the new table. If the ids (across different client dbs) are unique already then you can use same id in your new table.

From the application point view, it makes more sense to store clients in master table and reference the records by client id. It will help you to manage user/client level access in future.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining some more and balancing the alternatives. Accept one of the other answers, not mine.

### Composite keys

Darshan's suggestion of composite keys is usually preferable, assuming you don't know the customer identity associated with the data via some other means.

You can key everything with `(customerid, someid)`.

If you're using synthetic keys, though, this gets redundant fast, since usually `someid` will be unique for new rows, and `customerid` will be redundant.

The upside is that you don't have to walk all the way up a foreign key chain to some root customer record to find out if user 'jane' should be allowed to see invoice #1231423, though.

### Bitwise

If you track customer identity elsewhere and don't want to duplicate it in the keys themselves, midor is right. Use bitwise operations and bitshifting. To explain more directly, given db-id of `d integer` and row-id `r integer` (both signed 32-bit integers), create combined-id `c bigint` like this:

```
(CAST(d AS bigint) << 32) + CAST (r AS bigint)
```

Given `c bigint`, extract `d` and `r` respectively with

```
CAST (c >> 32 AS integer) AS d,
CAST (c & 2147483647 AS integer) AS r
```

(2147483647 is 0x7FFFFFFF, 32-bit maxint)

PostgreSQL supports these bitwise operations but not all SQL databases do, they aren't portable.

e.g for dbid 12, rowid 4412, the combined id is 51539611964.

You can avoid using a bigint if the bit-width of the biggest dbid plus the bit-width of the biggest row-id is less than 32. Given 1000 databases that's `ceil(log(2,1000))` = 10 bits for database ID (`1<<10` is 1024), leaving you 22 bits for row ids, i.e. a maximum value of `1<<22` or 4194304. So you probably need bigint key columns unless the DB is small.

Do NOT do this if you expect to be routinely extracting these "dbids" bitwise once you finish your migration. Use a composite key instead. This is ONLY suitable for data merging.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I went with the bitshifting, as it is a single import. By your request, I accepted the answer concerning bitshifting. But to be honest: I only really understood with your explanation :) Thanks!